# Topological Brauer group and sheaf of $C^{\infty}$-functions

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, sheaf-theory, brauer-groups

Given a smooth manifold $X$; by definition the topological Brauer group  $B(X)$ is the group of classes of Azumaya algebras over the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ of $\mathbb{C}$-valued functions on $X$.

If we replace the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ by the sheaf of $C^{\infty}$-functions; will the resulting Brauer group be the same?

Comment: Yes. In both cases you get  the torsion subgroup of $H^3(X,\mathbb{Z})$. This is discussed in this [Bourbaki seminar](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1964-1966__9__199_0.pdf) by Grothendieck: he treats the topological case, but the argument works also for the sheaf of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ functions.

Comment: Yes, because the elements of the Brauer group can be described as equivalence classes of complex projective bundles, and the topological and smooth classification of bundles coincide for spaces as nice as a smooth manifold.